# modifications to report don't migrate with change set

Tags: change-set

I've modified a report in dev and want to migrate it into another environment via change set. In the change set, I included the report, custom field that i added, and report folder. However, after the deployment to target succeeds, the report is still not updated with the latest change.
Am I missing a step?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the report's API name match exactly? In other words - are you sure you've updated existing one rather than created new report? And by deployment you mean really deployment, not only upload to target org without doing anything with it later? Stupid question but worth asking anyway...

Comment: I just verified that API name matches. And yes I clicked the deploy button in target after i uploaded it :-). Also, the report properties in target show that i was the one that changed the report and the date/time matches the deployment date/time.

Comment: Is it a brand new custom field? In that case - have you added the Profile(s) to the changeset too? If you didn't - check the field level security, I suspect it's set to invisible...

Comment: it's not a brand new field. However, i just compared field level security between source and target and they match.

Comment: Running out of ideas. If it would be a matter of field missing in custom report type then the deployment would fail... If Profile is OK... Does that field come from managed package or is somehow license-related and you don't have that license in target org? What happens when you modify the report manually? :(

Comment: I'm noticing that when I try to add the field manually, it doesn't exist the fields list for the report. However, the field does exist on the object. The report type is Opportunities. My understanding is that any new custom fields should automatically get added to the standard report type. Is this my problem? How do i get the field to show up as an available field on my report?

Comment: If it's really a std report type it should be there. Check if you have custom report type with same name. You'll also see what's used in the report when you inspect the XML of uploaded file, `<reportType>anything with "__c" here?</reportType>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report modifications were migrated successfully to target after I added all profiles into the change set.
Thank you for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

If change sets are not working for you, you could use Sublime Text.

First create the project in Sublime Text with no default components present.

The trick is to manually modify the Package.xml file once you have created your project from the org.

In Package.xml, add this section (for example):

```
<types>
    <members>My_folder/MY_Report</members>
    <members>My$other$folder/My_Other_Report</members>
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
```

[I haven't checked the various permutations related to spaces in folder names, but I am fairly sure that salesforce uses a '$' to represent them. It's perhaps safer not to use them]

Then pull down your report data from the org using the MavensMate->Project->Clean Project.
You should see a reports folder in the src folder.

Once you are happy with it, deploy to your production org.